# Its correct add private function to a Doctrine entity class

Tags: javascript, php

It's a correct design to add a private function in a doctrine entity class? The function a need returns boolean depending on a database field value.

Comment: Of course, you can define as many methods as you need. You have to take care of the visibility only if you need to call it outside the class, on the object variable. `$object->myCustomMethod()` in this case the method must be public.

Comment: Why shouldn't that be "correct design"? How do you define that term?